# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Customer with qualifiers @Default

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, managed-bean

I'm a Java EE-newbie. I want to test JSF and therefore made a simple program but can not deploy it. I get the following error message:

```
cannot Deploy onlineshop-war
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Customer with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.RegisterController.customer
at de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.RegisterController.customer(RegisterController.java:0)
. Please see server.log for more details.
```

My code is as follows:
Customer.java:

```
package de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model;

public class Customer {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

registerController.java:

```
package de.java2enterprise.onlineshop;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model.*;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RegisterController {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Customer customer;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public String persist() {
        return "/index.xhtml";
    }
}
```

For compiling it I had to include cdi-api.jar as an external library. Anyone here who could help me? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think your problem is that Customer is not @Named.

Comment: Is the `Customer` class known to CDI (such as a managed bean or a (local) EJB)?

Comment: Hey all, this is really helpful, thanks!! Actually, annotating the class "customer" with <Named> did not work, but with <Model> it worked. But why...?

Comment: Give you the correct and documented answer bellow.

Comment: As this is the most visited question in this topic, I add my 2 cents here. **If you happen to work in a multi module Maven environment, make sure to compile the module that contains your bean, after you added any of the below mentioned bean defining annotations**

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Your `Customer` class has to be discovered by CDI as a bean. For that you have two options:

1. Put a [bean defining annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) on it. As `@Model` is a stereotype it's why it does the trick. A qualifier like `@Named` is not a bean defining annotation, reason why it doesn't work
2. Change the [bean discovery mode in your bean archive](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive) from the default "annotated" to "all" by adding a `beans.xml` file in your jar.

Keep in mind that @Named has only one usage : expose your bean to the UI. Other usages are for bad practice or compatibility with legacy framework.

Comment: Hello,                                                                                                
The annotation Named is must for qualification. If same interface is implemented by different class, then @Named is must.  It must be used in this situation, not only for UI.                                                                            Regards                                                                                                                     Sanjeev

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. Could you please fix the first link? Thank you in advance!

Comment: My problem was that i used @Local annotation on the implementation not the interface

Answer (score 5):

it's also a good thing to make sure you have the right import

I had an issue like that and I found out that the bean was using

```
    javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
                 ^
```

instead of

```
    javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
                 ^
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but it had nothing to do with annotations. The problem happened while indexing beans in my container (Jboss EAP 6.3). One of my beans could not be indexed because it used Java 8 features an I got this sneaky little warning while deploying:

> WARN [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] ... Could not index class ... 
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=20 poolCount = 133

Then at the injection point I got the error:

> Unsatisfied dependencies for type ... with qualifiers @Default

The solution is to update the Java annotations index. download new version of jandex (jandex-1.2.3.Final or newer) then put it into

> JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\jandex\main and then update reference to the new file in module.xml

NOTE: EAP 6.4.x already have this fixed

Answer (score 3):

Similar problem here, for me the issue was that the bean class had no default constructor, so the framework was not able to instantiate it.

Make sure that your beans **always** have a constructor with the default (no-args) signature

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your Customer class with @Named or @Model annotation:

```
package de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model;
@Model
public class Customer {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

or create/modify beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: Using "@Named" will not help. "The @Named annotation is not what makes the class a bean.", [Weld docs, chapter 2.1.3. EL name](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/beanscdi.html#_el_name).

Answer (score -1):

When you change your project from "**war**" to "**jar**", like another friend said on Jboss Forum:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To inject an Object, its class must be known to the CDI mechanism. Usualy adding the @Named annotation will do the trick.

Comment: Wrong, "@Named" does not make a class into a bean.