# What type literal must I use to have CDI's Instance::select method work properly?

Tags: java, cdi

Suppose I have an interface like this:

```
public interface Converter<T> { /*...*/ }
```

And suppose in a CDI environment I have successfully done this:

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<Converter<?>> converters;
```

(By "successfully" I mean that I can do the following and see several converters in the output, so beans are being discovered and supplied properly:

```
for (final Object o : converters) {
  System.out.println("*** converter: " + o);
}
```

…so bean discovery is not the issue.)

And now suppose that given `Integer.class`, I'd like to do this:

```
final TypeLiteral<Converter<Integer>> typeLiteral = new TypeLiteral<Converter<Integer>>(){};
final Instance<Converter<Integer>> subInstance = converters.select(typeLiteral);
final Converter<Integer> converter = subInstance.get();
```

This works fine.

Now, in my actual code, `Integer.class` is passed in, as a value fulfilling a parameter declared as `Class<T>`, so what I really have is this:

```
final TypeLiteral<Converter<T>> typeLiteral = new TypeLiteral<Converter<T>>(){};
final Instance<Converter<T>> subInstance = converters.select(typeLiteral);
final Converter<T> converter = subInstance.get(); // this does not work
```

The `get()` call fails with a stack trace that starts with something that looks like the following:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001334: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Converter<T> with qualifiers @Any 
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:105)
```

What must I do to make this selection succeed?

One thing I notice is that the stack is reporting that a `Converter<T>` cannot be found.  This looks suspicious: I would have expected it to talk in terms of `Converter<Integer>` instead, since the `T` "slot" is being "filled" with `Integer.class` at runtime, although, to be fair, I did indeed supply a `new TypeLiteral<Converter<T>>(){}`, not `new TypeLiteral<Converter<Integer>>(){}`.

Anyway, all this tells me that `TypeLiteral<T>` is using `T` as the type to look for, not the actual value "filling" the `T` "slot", and indeed, there is no converter declared as `implements Converter<T>`, only a converter declared as `implements Converter<Integer>`, and so I'm worried that what I'd like to do here is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but do you have a beans.xml defined with your injectable dependencies listed (or not listed)

Comment: Yes; I should have mentioned that I can successfully iterate over the `converters` object, and can see that there are several that are found.

Comment: This could be to do with `new TypeLiteral<Converter<T>>(){}` - `T` is not known at compile-time so it will represent the type `Converter<Object>`, not `Converter<T>`.

Comment: @JosephEarl I believe you are correct. It would appear that I cannot do what I want this way. Seen through this lens it looks like `Instance::select(TypeLiteral)` is intended for compile-time-resolvable types only. It would be nice to be able to select at runtime as well. Oh well.  If you write your comment up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Perhaps you can have the caller pass the TypeLiteral to your class/method so that where the TypeLiteral is created in code the type is known, but your class can still be generic and not know about the exact type.

For instance this should work: 
`Converter<T> getConverter(TypeLiteral<Converter<T>> typeLiteral) { 
Instance<Converter<T>> subInstance = converters.select(typeLiteral);
Converter<T> converter = subInstance.get();
return converter; 
}`

provided the caller knows the type of converter they want at compile time.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Thanks again for your comments and answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a `TypeLiteral` to capture generic parameters only works if those parameters are known at compile time, so `new TypeLiteral<Converter<Integer>>(){}`.

If the type parameter is not known at compile time then a TypeLiteral cannot capture the parameter information because that information has been removed due to type erasure. So creating a `new TypeLiteral<Converter<T>>(){}` actually just creates a `new TypeLiteral<Converter<object>>(){}`.

This means your `select(typeLiteral)` will not work as expected since it will receive the type literal for `Converter<object>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Converter interface has not been discovered by CDI.  You can do so by adding annotation scope to the interface or by having it be discovered through the beans.xml configuration file.

This [WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Customer with qualifiers @Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352461/weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependencies-for-type-customer-with-qualifiers-default) has a much better explanation.

Comment: Thanks, but when I iterate over the `converters` object, as described, I can see all my converters.