# Error : WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default

Tags: websphere, jersey-2.0, websphere-liberty

I am trying to develop Jersey 2 + Spring 3 application and run it on my local on Websphere Liberty server.Code is building/compiling fine,but it gives following exception on start of websphere liberty server on my local:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application abcEar.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the application abcEar. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)
```

My dependencies in POM :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <properties>
        <jersey2.version>2.23.2</jersey2.version>
<jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>

        <application.systemletters>ABC</application.systemletters>
        <oracle.jdbc.version>10.2.0.4</oracle.jdbc.version>

        <!-- See RAD: Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > text file encoding. 
            Default=cp1252 (== ISO-8859-1 == ISO-Latin-1) -->
        <!-- <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1251</project.build.sourceEncoding> -->

        <!-- Sometimes the sources itself should not be loaded in Sonar for some 
            reason -->
        <sonar.importSources>false</sonar.importSources>

        <sonar.skipDesign>true</sonar.skipDesign>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS</maven.build.timestamp.format>

        <!-- Libraries -->
        <junit>4.12</junit>
        <springframework>3.1.0.RELEASE</springframework>
    </properties>



    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- Jersey 2 starts -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
            </dependency> 
<!-- Jersey 2.23.2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
            </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

            <!-- Jersey dependencies Starts -->
                <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Jersey dependencies Ends -->

            <!-- Spring data jpa dependencies Starts -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>

            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency> 
            <!-- Spring data jpa dependencies Starts -->

            <!-- Spring dependencies Starts -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework}</version>
            </dependency>
                <!-- Spring dependencies Ends -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
            </dependency> -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.21</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
              <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
              <version>1.10.19</version>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
              <version>0.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Can anyone please tell the reason for above error.

Comment: If [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352461/weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependencies-for-type-customer-with-qualifiers-default) doesn't help you, please include more details like your server config (server.xml) and some code snippets.